# Connection String for SQL Server Instance

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, instance, named-pipes

I have SQL server 2000, and it have 2 other sql instances as well. Main sever has no issues, hereafter I am talking about those two instances,

They share,

> 1. Same machine
> 2. Same IP
> 3. Same Instance Name
> 4. Same Port

I too wonder how it has done.

Using query analyzer Once connect to,

```
MyServer\Invent (it connects to first instance)
MyServer\Invent,1433 (it connects to second instance)
```

(Yeah, it happens. I am 100% sure on that because I have separate DBs inside them)

Now it comes to problem,

With C# SqlConnection, I am unable to connect to first one, but can connect to second.

```
1. Data Source=MyServer\Invent;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=TEST;uid=admin;pwd=123
2. Data Source=MyServer\Invent,1433;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=TEST;uid=admin;pwd=123
```

Once I used 1st Connection String it hangs for a while and gets following error message...

"*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*"

Searched on net for this, many says installing such is possible. And one connection should use named pipes (tcp/445)

Any idea how to resolve this ?
Any possible Connection String format ?
Anyway of making Connection String for named pipes ?

Comment: FYI, I have just checked from Ports using "Enterprise Manager" Both share 1433. No doubt on that.

Comment: Firewall issue perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your first instance is not actually listening on 1433, even though that is usually the default.

I believe it's possible to change the default port with the SQL Server Configuration utility. Check what the default port is, and assuming it's not 1433, try specifying it in the first connection string.

Here's [some info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938) about how to check which port your instance is listening on.

**Edit:** Ok, the first instance is listening on a named pipe. Maybe `server=np:MyServer\Invent;` will work, as per [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313295).

Comment: I checked that too... I am 100% confident on that. I have used following SP to check the port

DECLARE @tcp_port nvarchar(5)

EXEC xp_regread
@rootkey    =    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
@key        =    'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLSERVER\SUPERSOCKETNETLIB\TCP',
@value_name =    'TcpPort',
@value        =    @tcp_port OUTPUT

select @tcp_port

Comment: Have you tried `Use master Go Xp_readerrorlog` and look for "listening on x.x.x.x:yyyy" ?

Comment: @ Blorgbeard, tried I think there is a clue, I got following for those two instances.

1.SQL server listening on Shared Memory, Named Pipes.
2.SQL server listening on 172.16.80.25: 1433.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the one server is using a different port. So it's using TCP but a different port and you'll need to figure out what port is it using and then add that port to your connection string like you're doing with the other instance (1433).

you SQL Server configuration manager.
Navigate to the SQL Server Network Configuration Node and expand it.
Locate the instance in the children nodes
Now on the right hand side you'll see Protocols (Shared Memory, Named Pipes, TCP etc.)
Double Click on TCP.
In the dialog that pops up, switch to the IP Address tab.
Scroll all the way down to the "IP All" section

What does it say for TCP Port?
[image]

Comment: I checked that too... I am 100% confident on that. I have used following SP to check the port DECLARE @tcp_port nvarchar(5) EXEC xp_regread @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLSERVER\SUPERSOCKETNETLIB\TCP', @value_name = 'TcpPort', @value = @tcp_port OUTPUT select @tcp_port

Comment: What about the other instance? And do both instances have TCP enabled?

Comment: What about firewall issues. Can you run a test application on the box itself? That way you'll eliminate any firewall issues.

Comment: Both instances use 1433

I can connect through Enterprise Manager and Query Analyzer. So I hope that means there cannot be any Fire Wall restrictions.

Comment: From your computer you can connect to both instances? Yes, then there are no firewall issues. Try using the Network Library parameter in your connection string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.71).aspx and use Namedpipes

Comment: I'd still try running a test application on the server machine. Make a simple gui that allows you to provide the connection string and then connect/disconnect. That way you can experiment on the server machine.

Comment: Please tell me how to use "Named Pipes" in Connection String...Or how to do it in C#.Net

I cannot runn applications on Server

Comment: The link I provided explains how to get it to use NamedPipes. You need to specify the Network Library parameter in your connection string. Net=dbnmpntw for example. This link gives you a few examples and is quite detailed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189307.aspx

Comment: You can also use this query (from your Query analyzer instance) ot see what protocol the two instances are using.  SELECT net_transport 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
WHERE session_id = @@SPID;